# TypeError: Cannot read property 'opts' of undefined from google-auth-library

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to fetch the tokens from the google for a particular user.
My code is as follows:

```
const util = require('util');
    return util.promisify(oauth2Client.getToken, {context: oauth2Client})(googleToken).then(tokens => {
      locals.tokens = tokens;
      oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
      return util.promisify(gAuth.userinfo.get, {context: gAuth})({ userId: 'me', auth: oauth2Client });
    })
```

I get an error on executing the code. The error is as follows:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'opts' of undefined from google-auth-library

Comment: @str. The node version is `8.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

Promise.promisify is not an official function from the spec, but many implementation exist

Like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html)

EDIT:

Node8 seems to have an [util function](http://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html)

Comment: Thanks @Varkal. Implemented the util function and am facing a new error. The error is `Cannot read property then of undefined`

Comment: Have updated the code by implementing `util function`

Comment: And your import ?

Comment: Have updated the question again @Varkal. You may refer that.